# Inserting a string into a postgreSQL table with php

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to INSERT 3 individual variables from a php array to a postgreSQL table with this method

```
    $raw = fread($file,filesize("artists.txt"));
    $array_enters = (explode("\n",$raw));
    $arrlength = count($array_enters);

    for($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; $i++) {
    $arr_line = (explode("|",$array_enters[$i]));

    $sql ="
    INSERT INTO Artists (artist_name,popularity,link_ar) VALUES('$arr_line[0]','$arr_line[1]','$arr_line[2]');
    ";
    }
```

However, I get a table populated with only the last entry of my file

```
                          link_ar                          |  artist_name   | popularity 
-----------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------

 https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6sq7prp0tj9Abn89khmfja | Dead Can Dance |         51
(1 row)
```

It seems to overwrite all my other entries because when I try `for($i = 0; $i < $arrlength - 1; $i++)` I get the table with only the second to last entry

What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: you're not executing the `$sql` INSIDE your loop, so you must be executing it OUTSIDE of the loop, which means you'll only ever get the LAST `$sql` you produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't execute your sql string inside the for loop.

Every time you write **$sql = "";**, it is overwriting the previous declaration.

If you then run the query AFTER the loop, it will, naturally, only be able to run it on the one entry.

Solutions: Either run the query inside the for loop, or append the queries to each other using **$sql .= "";** (Notice the fullstop/period. You also need to ensure that you have a semi-colon inside the quoted sql string, which you currently do).

Either way, you should also escape your sql strings and look into prepared statements so that your database is less vulnerable to sql injection.